# How can I navigate two pages deep in a single apparent operation

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-7

I have a scenario where page A can navigate to page B, and page B can navigate to page C, but A can also navigate to C and I want B to be inserted in the stack so that navigating back from C always ends on B.

More graphically, I want to allow these navigations:

- `A --> B --> C (back) B (back) A` (normal navigation)
- `A --> C (back) B (back) A` (as if B was always between A and C)

The simple answer is to set a bit in my viewmodel that tells B to navigate to C right away after loading. Is there a cleaner way? Apart from the design guidelines, are there other reasons against this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: The only reason I can think not to do this would be the potential for confusing the user. If you have a good reason to do it then I don't see why not though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the advice you're getting on the wp7 forums is pretty accurate for this question. I would have suggested the same considerations.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/5249e520-e170-4f32-9f58-764870eb14af